# FBProfilePictureView - Save UIImage to UserDefaults

Tags: xcode, facebook, uiimage, profile, facebook-ios-sdk

How do I get the UIImage out from the FBProfilePictureView? I couldn't find a post that explained it properly so check out my answer below and feel free to edit it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a question I was looking for on here the other day but couldn't find a correct answer that worked so I thought I'd answer my own for the community. Here goes:

You will need to have already setup a login button with the:

```
- (void)fbMethodLoggedInWithFbUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
```

delegate method already working.

We'll use a login screen with a 'Continue' button after loggin=Success to capture the UIImage, so add a "Continue" button (for pushing to the next screen after login) onto your storyboard and also a View with the class of "FBProfilePictureView" which is linked to the header file like so:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *userProfilePic;
```

Then synthesise it in the .m file like so:

```
@synthesise userProfilePic;
```

Then set the Delegate in ViewDidLoad like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [userProfilePic setDelegate:self];
}
```

Now we want to add this line anywhere in the .m file (make sure it's not nested inside a function!)

```
id<FBGraphUser>cachedUser;
```

Inside the Delegate method we mentioned earlier (fbMethodLoggedInWithFbUser) we will set our newly created id tag to equal the passthrough value of the delegate method like so:

```
- (void)fbMethodLoggedInWithFbUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    cachedUser = user;

    // other login methods go here

}
```

Now your user is logged in, we have a cache of the '' id. The reason that this works best with a 'Continue' button after the user has logged in, is because the code I'm going to post will fetch the default blank profile picture image that Facebook uses as a temp image until the users profile picture loads. So to make sure this doesn't happen, first add in these 2 methods, then we will link the first up to the 'Continue' button action:

```
- (void)getProfilePictureWithFbUser:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    userProfilePic.profileID = user.id;
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.4f];
    [userProfilePic setAlpha:1];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

    // -----------------------
    // CATCH PROFILE PICTURE::

    for (id obj in userProfilePic.subviews) {
        if ([obj isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            UIImageView *tempImageView = obj;
            UIImage *tempImage = tempImageView.image;
            [self saveImageToUDWithImage:tempImage];
        }
    }

}
```

This method is to save our captured UIImage from the 'userProfilePic' view to the UserDefaults:

```
- (void)saveImageWithUDWithImage:(UIImage *)tempImage {

    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [ud setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(tempImage) forKey:@"userProfilePicture"];
    [ud synchronize];

}
```

Now set up your continue button like so:

```
- (IBAction)continueButtonActionAfterLogin:(id)sender {

    // First we capture the user profile pic
    // with the cached id we got earlier after
    // login:

    [self captureProfilePicWithFBUser:cachedUser];

    // You can execute model pushes here, etc...

}
```

Then to read the UIImage from the UserDefaults later on, use this method:

```
- (UIImage *)loadProfilePicFromUserDefaults {
    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *imageData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userProfilePicture"];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
    return image;
}
```

This can be called in any other class that you want to display the user profile picture in like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [myWantingToBeProfilePicture setImage:[self loadProfilePicFromUserDefaults];

}
```

Sorry for code being allover the place, but I've explained it in a way that made it clear to me, I just hope it's clear to everyone else too! Feel free to edit it and make it better!

@Declanland